# Seekbar.getRight() and Seekbar.getLeft() is returning 0

Tags: android

I am working in android. I want to add functionality of seekbar in my application.

This is my xml file:-

```
  <SeekBar

        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incentives_textViewBottemLeft"
        android:max="10"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/incentive_progress"
        android:secondaryProgress="0"
        android:thumb="@drawable/incentives_progress_pin" />


And this is my java code related to this seek bar. 

 mSkbSample = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar01);

  v1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.incentives_textViewAbove_process_pin);


v1.setText(String.valueOf(progress).toCharArray(), 0, String.valueOf(progress).length());   


 mSkbSample.setProgress(progress);


 int xPos = ((mSkbSample.getRight() - mSkbSample.getLeft()) * mSkbSample.getProgress()) / mSkbSample.getMax();

 v1.setPadding(xPos,0,0,0);
```

I tried to print `mSkbSample.getRight()`and `mSkbSample.getLeft()`, this always returning zero.
 help me to find out what mistake i have done.

Comment: are you doing this in onCreate?

Comment: yes sir i doing this in onCreate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wont get the getRight value in onCreate because the UI hasn't been drawn on the screen so none of the UI elements are measure yet. Try this

```
SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.YOUD VIEW ID); 
ViewTreeObserver vto = seekbar.getViewTreeObserver();  
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onGlobalLayout() {  
        this.seekbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);  
        int left = seekbar.getLeft(); 
    }  
});
```

Put the code in the onCreate method. This will get called after the seekbar has been laid out. You should get the left value now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are required to add

android:progress and android:secondaryProgress with some values.

you can check the example below:

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/06/how-to-use-seekbar-in-android/

Thanks,
Shafali

Comment: Dear shafali, i want to show that text view on the exact place where my progress thumb is exist.

Comment: I am also looking for the exact thing like R Fauzdar